# How to have date driven actions in Asp.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an Asp.Net Core Web application and I need to mark the deadlines as "passed" or something like that in the last day set. The administrator can add a deadline and the other users must send their options until the last day set by the admin. How can I update the deadline automatically, on the server? I was thinking to use Ajax(when a document is loaded, the client will make a call and the deadline will be set if it is expired), but I want to know if there is a solution that is just on the server, without help from the client. I don't want to use the ajax solution because I don't want to have too many redundant calls to the server. Thank you!

Comment: If you are looking for job sheduling you can look at [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) or [background service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since .NET Core 2.0, the framework provides a new interface named **IHostedService** helping you to easily implement hosted services. By using it, you could run a background service or build a scheduled task in the background. More detail information, please check the following articles:

[Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

[Building a scheduled task in ASP.NET Core/Standard 2.0](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2017/08/01/building-a-scheduled-cache-updater-in-aspnet-core-2.html)